# How to protect my Azure web role from other people?

Tags: azure, firewall

I have a Web role on Azure. I would like to allow only my people to access the web role. 
I have found post to manual/code to restrict IPs to access the role. I would like to create firewall way(something like SQL Azure's firewall) to block/allow IPs.

I could not find any setting in Azure console. please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you publish your endpoint on the Internet through the Windows Azure load balancer, there is no option in place to define firewall rules on Azure.

But you can secure access to VMs created using either Windows Azure’s Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) technology or its Platform as a Service (PaaS) technology through the Windows Azure Virtual Network service.

Windows Azure Virtual Network lets you create a logical boundary around a group of VMs, called a virtual network or VNET, in a Windows Azure datacenter. It then lets you establish an IPsec connection between this VNET and your local network.

For more information see [Networking](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/networking/), [Windows Azure Networking](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/fundamentals/networking/), [Windows Azure Virtual Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156007.aspx), [Create a Virtual Network for Cross-Premises Connectivity](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/cross-premises-connectivity/), [Create a Virtual Network in Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/create-a-virtual-network/).

About the cost of this service: Windows Azure Virtual Network is currently (February 2013) available in preview at no charge. Once the service becomes generally available you will be charged if you create a hardware VPN connection between a Virtual Network (VNET) and your VPN gateway. The charge will be for each hour that the VPN connection is provisioned and available (called the “VPN connection hour”). All data transferred over the VPN connection is charged at Window Azure’s standard data transfer rates. You can use the [pricing calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=full) for a simulation.

Comment: thank you. i have read the posts/documents. i think i need http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/cross-premises-connectivity/. i also need to work with network administrator to get it up.

Comment: i have look at price for networking. it said that $0.05 per hour. Is there additional price (like number of size of data)?

Comment: You'll also pay for outgoing bandwidth. Editing the answer to clarify billing.

Comment: Regarding the size of data, the typical data transfer rules still apply. If its inside of Azure, then data transfer is "free". If you're uploading to Azure, it's "free". If you're downloading, it costs bandwidth. And then you have the appropriate storage transaction costs, depending on what's being accessed from where.