# Good coding practices to protect a cloud hosted IPN listener service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am using a shared cloud hosting service (Azure) which listens for / handles HTTP requests from an IPN server. The listener service validates the request with the calling IPN server, stores it in an MSMQ and a worker roll picks it up for processing. This is fairly high/medium use with many thousands of messages anticipated per month.

Since the cloud hosting service does not allow you to firewall incoming requests to specific IPs ([How to protect my Azure web role from other people?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091763/how-to-protect-my-azure-web-role-from-other-people)), I need to do the best I can to make the service invulnerable to attack assuming hackers will attempt to bring this service down or otherwise make it unavailable by spamming it. Or, potentially causing huge usage fee's with Azure.

The question is two fold:

1. Should I be concerned about this at all?
2. What is the best way to prevent this from happening. Keeping in mind:
   this is an IPN service. Really, it's just a page which validates the HTTP request message and passes it to a queue if it's valid.

I can restrict in code so it only attempts to validate a request if it's from the correct IP. What else can / should be done?